# New site is not listed when adding new domain controller

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

I inherited this network and I'm trying to figure out what I am missing. I created a new site in Chicago and I want to add a domain controller to it but the new site is not listed when I go to configure the new domain controlller.

The new site is called Chicago-Site.

[image]

I thought I had added it correctly. I have assigned the appropriate ip addresses.

But when I go to configure the domain controller, the new site is not listed:

[image]

What do I need to check or what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has the new site that you created on one DC synchronized to all of the other DCs in your environment? You can force replication throughout the enterprise using `repadmin /syncall /aped`.

If that doesn't work, look at your event logs, since that would seem to point to replication failures.

Comment: I ran that command and it didn't help. So, I restarted the new DC and it saw the Chicago server. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

1. Check in DNS if Sites have been updated and created
2. Restarted DNS Server
3. Close Server Manager
4. Open Server Manager
5. Promote the new ADDC Server
6. Select your Site now :)